# How to set the view location in Joomla 4

Tags: mvc, view, joomla-4.x

I'm rebuilding a component called `DogWalk` for Joomla 4 and I've tried to ensure I'm doing exactly what the core `Banners` component does. I've named and namespaced my files, named my directories identically to how `Banners` does it, but I can't get the `BaseController` to find my view file.

I'm dumping the `$this->paths` array from `BaseController::createView`, and the path is the same for `Banners` and for `DogWalk`:

```
array (size=1)
  'view' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '/Users/mystuff/Sites/joomla4/administrator/components/com_dogwalk/views/'
```

However my component is looking for a file called `mycomponentViewviewname` while the actual view class name for `Banners` (and all the other admin components) is just `HtmlView`. Furthermore the `Banners` view class is found even though it's in `View`, not `views` (despite what `$config` array says).

How do I define where the controller will find my views, and what naming convention they would use?

Comment: Is your component properly namespaced? Is its record present in `libraries/autoload_psr4.php` file?

Comment: You know that you really do not have to define any location for the view since the controller automatically finds it. You see the `createView()` and `getView()` methods of the BaseController, then you of course know how it finds the view, if you set your component correctly. I do not really see any good answer on your question here, since most probably you'll will find a typo as usually these questions end up...

Comment: @Sharky there is no line for my component in the `libraries/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` file-- should that be automatically reloaded when you install a component?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong file. The file I mentioned, `libraries/autoload_psr4.php`, should get updated when installing extensions if `Extension - Namespace Updater` plugin is enabled.

Comment: @Sharky thanks, I verified that the plugin was working as expected and had added the namespace in the `libraries/autload_psr4.php`. Still not loading the files, but at least we can rule that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped. The issue appears to have been the `services` file, not my pathing or namespacing. Once I added a file in `administrator/services/provider.php` it all started to work automagically. The file looked like this:

```
return new class implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Registers the service provider with a DI container.
     *
     * @param   Container  $container  The DI container.
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   4.0.0
     */
    public function register(Container $container)
    {
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new MVCFactory('\\Mycompany\\Component\\Mycomponent'));
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new ComponentDispatcherFactory('\\Mycompany\\Component\\Mycomponent'));

        $container->set(
            ComponentInterface::class,
            function (Container $container)
            {
                $component = new CategoriesComponent($container->get(ComponentDispatcherFactoryInterface::class));

                $component->setMVCFactory($container->get(MVCFactoryInterface::class));
                $component->setRegistry($container->get(Registry::class));

                return $component;
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Another thing I needed to add was the generic `DisplayController` in both the admin and site `Controller` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The view file that your component is looking for `MycomponentViewViewname` which was used in the Joomla 3, so make sure you are extending the right controller class in your Controller(i.e `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController` or any other class extending it such as `AdminController`). If it is from correct namespace track the `setView()` for any such changes that can cause the problem.

If this doesn't solve your problem then debugging the whole flow will be the option.
But before that, I will suggest running the extension on some other fresh Joomla 4 setup on default parameters(as maybe some changes are affecting it such as code changes or plugin overrides).

If you are unable to find any solution you can override the `setView()` method in your controller as per your need(this should be the last option).

Hope this might help. Do let us know the solution once you find it.